# g++.exe: installation problem, cannot exec `as': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, g++

I'm trying to learn C++, I downloaded and installed g++ on Windows using Cygwin, following this tutorial:
[https://www.cs.odu.edu/~zeil/cs250PreTest/latest/Public/installingACompiler/#installing-the-mingw-compiler](https://www.cs.odu.edu/%7Ezeil/cs250PreTest/latest/Public/installingACompiler/#installing-the-mingw-compiler)

Just like in the tutorial, at the end, I check that g++ is installed:

```
PS D:\Desktop\coursera_ODS_in_c-\Week 2> g++ --version
g++.exe (GCC) 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)
Copyright (C) 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

and then I try to run this code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int num = 7;
    
    std::cout << "Values:" << num << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Address: " << &num << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

by using this

```
PS D:\Desktop\coursera_ODS_in_c-\Week 2> g++ main.cpp
```

but I get this:

```
g++.exe: installation problem, cannot exec `as': No such file or directory
```

Do you how to solve this ?

Comment: `g++ --version` what is the response of this command ?

Comment: @UmarFarooq: the version response is right at the top of the question.

Comment: `g++ -c main.cpp` i guess you are missing the compiliation flag

Comment: You have a _very_ old version of g++

Comment: You must have a really old version of cygwin for it to install a 16 year old version of g++

Comment: I just downloaded the cygwin installer, ran it and let it update everything it wanted to update. I haven't done that for a long time so my `g++` went from `7.4.0` to `9.3.0`.

What does the command `cygcheck --check-setup | grep binutils` report and what does `cygcheck --check-setup | grep -v ' OK$'` report? (that last command should be `grep -v ' OK$'`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message:

```
g++.exe: installation problem
```

clearly states that something's wrong with the installation of your G++ compiler. Also, 3.4.5 version is too old. The current stable release is 10.2 (released on July 23, 2020), reinstalling it with the latest version will probably solve your issue. (Since insufficient details are given, the error cause is still a mystery.)

Try downloading the GNU GCC compiler which comes with the latest edition: [GNU GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/).

OTOH, the program is coded properly, no error reported on [OnlineGDB](https://onlinegdb.com/HJQl9hZMw).

Comment: The last stable GCC is 10.2, so no, TDM-GCC doesn't ship the latest version.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks, I just got to know by Googling. I've edited the answer.

Comment: If you follow the link to gcc.gnu.org and look for binaries for cygwin you are directed to https://sourceware.org/cygwin/ and http://www.mingw.org/. I think the proper action is to update cygwin itself by downloading and running the installer again.

Comment: It'd be interesting to hear _what_ solved the problem exactly. I don't understand how that link to https://gcc.gnu.org/ could have helped.